# New Entity is created with every Persist JPA

Tags: jpa, entity

I just get started with JPA. I have an entity `CustomerOrderEntity` which has `@OneToMany` relation with another entity `BeverageEntity`. When I add the `BeverageEntity` to the `CustomerOrderEntity` a new entity is created of the type `BeverageEntity` and is persisted in the database as a new record. I do not want something like that I only need the `CustomerOrderEntity` to have the record of `BeverageEntity` and a new entity is not created for that inside the database.

These two entities are invoked from this class `SalesManagement`:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(SalesManagement.class)
public class SalesManagementBean implements SalesManagement {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void createOrder(CustomerOrder order) {

        order.getOrderItems().forEach(item -> {
            updateBeverageQuantity(item.getId(), item.getQuantity());
        });

        CustomerOrderEntity customerOrderEntity = new CustomerOrderEntity();
        customerOrderEntity.setIssueDate(order.getIssueDate());
        order.getOrderItems().forEach(item ->{
            customerOrderEntity.addOrder(toEntity(item));
        });
        em.persist(customerOrderEntity);
    }

    public void updateBeverageQuantity(int b_id, int quantity) {
        BeverageEntity beverageEntity = em.find(BeverageEntity.class, b_id);
        if(beverageEntity != null) {
            beverageEntity.setQuantity(beverageEntity.getQuantity() - quantity);
            em.persist(beverageEntity);
        }
    }

    public List<BeverageEntity> toBeverageEntity(List<Beverage> beverages) {
        List<BeverageEntity> entities = new ArrayList<BeverageEntity>();

        if(beverages != null && beverages.size() > 0) {
            beverages.forEach(beverage -> {
                BeverageEntity entity = new BeverageEntity();
                entity.setName(beverage.getName());
                entity.setManufacturer(beverage.getManufacturer());
                entity.setQuantity(beverage.getQuantity());
                entity.setPrice(beverage.getPrice());
                entity.setIncentiveEntity(toIncentiveEntity(beverage.getIncentiveDTO()));
                entities.add(entity);
            });

            return entities;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public IncentiveEntity toIncentiveEntity(IncentiveDTO incentiveDTO) {
        if(incentiveDTO != null) {
            IncentiveEntity entity = null;
            return entity;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public BeverageEntity toEntity(Beverage b) {
        BeverageEntity entity = new BeverageEntity();
        entity.setName(b.getName());
        entity.setManufacturer(b.getManufacturer());
        entity.setQuantity(b.getQuantity());
        entity.setPrice(b.getPrice());
        entity.setIncentiveEntity(toIncentiveEntity(b.getIncentiveDTO()));

        return entity;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in the method `toBeverageEntity`. But I am not sure about it.

The `CustomerOrderEntity`:

```
@Entity
public class CustomerOrderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    @Version
    private int version;

    private Date issueDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BeverageEntity> beverageEntities;

    public void addOrder(BeverageEntity beverageEntity) {
        this.beverageEntities.add(beverageEntity);
    }

    public List<BeverageEntity> getBeverageEntities() {
        return beverageEntities;
    }

    public void setBeverageEntities(List<BeverageEntity> beverageEntities) {
        this.beverageEntities = beverageEntities;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Date getIssueDate() {
        return issueDate;
    }

    public void setIssueDate(Date issueDate) {
        this.issueDate = issueDate;
    }
}
```

The `BeverageEntity`:

```
@Entity
public class BeverageEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String manufacturer;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;


    @Version
    private int version;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private IncentiveEntity incentiveEntity;

    public BeverageEntity() {

    }

    public BeverageEntity(String name, String manufacturer, int quantity, Double price, IncentiveEntity entity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.incentiveEntity = entity;
    }

    public BeverageEntity(String name, String manufacturer, int quantity, Double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public IncentiveEntity getIncentiveEntity() {
        return incentiveEntity;
    }

    public void setIncentiveEntity(IncentiveEntity incentiveEntity) {
        this.incentiveEntity = incentiveEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why downvote if you can not comment/suggest something.

Comment: You have to implement beverageEntities as Set and implement equals/hashCode on the BeverageEntity

Comment: If you don't want the `PERSIST` to create a new record, remove the association? Is there any circumstance under which you do wish to persist a record of the BeverageEntities associated with a CustomerOrder? If not, it shouldn't be an `Entity` at all. If yes, you need to make sure that you retrieve the _existing_ BeverageEntity from the database and add that to the list instead of creating a brand new one each time. Unfortunately your question isn't 100% clear on how you'd like this to work exactly.

Comment: There is a relation between  Order and Beverage entities. The user orders a beverage using the frontend JSP so on the backend I need to have the record of the order which contains the beverage which the user ordered and then I have to modify the quantity inside the beverage entity and persist the updated entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem it was in the method `toBeverageEntity` as pointed out in the comments I was creating a new entity that was wrong. I needed to use `find` because the entity is already in the database.

```
BeverageEntity entity = em.find(BeverageEntity.class, beverage.getId());
                entities.add(entity);
```